# grep for a string in a line if the previous line doesn't contain a specific string

Tags: unix, grep

I have the following lines in a file:

```
abcdef ghi jkl
uvw xyz
```

I want to grep for the string "xyz" if the previous line is not contains the string "jkl".

I know how to grep for a string if the line doesn't contains a specific string using -v option. But i don't know how to do this with different lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` is really a line-oriented tool. It might be possible to achieve what you want with it, but it's easier to use Awk:

```
awk '
  /xyz/ && !skip { print }
                 { skip = /jkl/ }
' file
```

Read as: for every line, do

- if the current line matches `xyz` and we haven't just seen `jkl`, print it;
- set the variable `skip` to indicate whether we've just seen `jkl`.

Comment: Thank you. I need to explore a lot in awk :-/

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed '/jkl/{N;d}; /xyz/!d'
```

- If find `jkl`, remove that line and next
- print only remaining lines with `xyz`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off using an actual programming language, even a simple one like Bash or AWK or sed. For example, using Bash:

```
(
  previous_line_matched=
  while IFS= read -r line ; do
    if [[ ! "$previous_line_matched" && "$line" == *xyz* ]] ; then
      echo "$line"
    fi
    if [[ "$line" == *jkl* ]] ; then
      previous_line_matched=1
    else
      previous_line_matched=
    fi
  done < input_file
)
```

Or, more tersely, using Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if m/xyz/ && ! $skip; $skip = m/jkl/' < input_file
```