# monit alert based of previous log line in check file

Tags: lines, logfile, monit, alerts

In the following auth.log

```
Mon DD HH:MM:SS SFTPHOST internal-sftp[21583]: realpath "/path/to/*.txt"
Mon DD HH:MM:SS SFTPHOST internal-sftp[21583]: sent status No such file
```

I only want an alert on "sent status No such file" IFF the previous line does NOT contain *.  As a stretch goal it would be **nice** to check that that line has the same PID (number in the square brackets).

Any way to do that?  Or am I using the wrong tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a [`CHECK PROGRAM`](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Program) combined with a custom script that will do all the hard work (something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17228241/374236 if I understand you correctly).